Unable to Access Media Gallery - Getting 404 Error
I'm encountering an issue when trying to navigate to Media > Media Gallery in the Magento admin panel. It's displaying an error like this
404 error: Page not found.
Does anyone have any suggestions on what might be causing this issue or how I can resolve it? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Have you check magento log for the same?

Please add the video, to let us know that which steps are you following, as in admin there is no menu called MEDIA.
